# Accessing a list of objects & how to claim a object for the fatest request

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, locking, signalr

I'm developing an Asp.net mvc project:

There is a List store all the online Pupils

There are few methods:
- Login(Pupil p): if login ok, p will be added to Pupils list
- Logout(Pupil p): if logout ok, p will be removed out of Pupil list

-> 2 methods have a same potential issue is "cannot modify list while modifying" because there are a lot of Pupil login to system and logout at the same time. While adding a pupil the other are being removed from Pupils list -> exception throws

I tried to use lock to lock a list while modifying (insert/remove) but is it a good way to do? Do you have some better idea?

The last method is Claim(Book b)

Administrator put some books in the GUI and all the logged Pupils can see these books. They can claim any book they want. The fastest Pupil claimed is will own that book. So how can we know the fastest claimer? While updating a data row. At the same time there are many books are claimed by many pupils. But only one fastest pupil can own a particular book after claiming successfully

Do you have a solution for this? This solution just like you put a command to buy stocks. The fastest guy will own the stocks

Remember that there are many pupils will do the same thing at the same time. So we have to make sure that system works properly and exactly

Thanks you in advance,
Best regards

Comment: Are you just using a List<Pupil>? If so, that's never deemed to be thread safe. Have you tried using a Concurrent bag? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Shane.C I will try it

Answer (score 0):

The issue I see here is that your design assumes that the application is always on, and that the lists are the absolute truth about who has what book. What happens when the server is reset? What if your library gets big enough to need a second server to the application?

You need to preserve your lists in a database or some other sort of persistent medium. Holding the lists in memory will give you a read/write buffer, but the lists must be populated from the persistence layer of your library database.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;


namespace TestArea
{
    public class Pupil
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string UserName { get; set; }        
    }

    public class Book
    {
        //Supports having more than one ISBN in the library... We may have more than one To Kill a Mockingbird in our school library
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string ISBN { get; set; }
    }
    public class SchoolLibrary
    {
        private ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Pupil> Pupils { get; set; }
        private ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Book> Books{ get; set; }
        private ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Guid> CheckOuts { get; set; }

        public Pupil Login(string userName, string password)
        {
            //Call repository to authenticate pupil into library system

            //Mocked return assuming password check success
            var id = Guid.NewGuid();

            return Pupils.GetOrAdd(id, (i) =>
            {
                //Replace with function to get student info
                return new Pupil
                {
                    Id = i,
                    Name = "Bac Clunky",
                    UserName = userName
                };
            });
        }

        public bool CheckOut(Guid pupilId, Guid bookId)
        {
            //If book exists
            if (Books.ContainsKey(bookId))
            {
                Guid currentOwner;
                //...is not currently checked out by anyone
                if (CheckOuts.TryAdd(bookId, pupilId))
                {
                    return true; //book is now checked out
                }

                if (CheckOuts.TryGetValue(bookId, out currentOwner))
                {
                    return currentOwner == pupilId; //returns true if pupil already has the book, false if another student has it
                }                    
            }

            return false; //all other cases fail to check out book
        }
    }
}
```